# Extract info from zepp in python

Tags: python, android, extract, watch, info

I need to take information from the "Zepp" app for use in another project.
If possible in python but it's ok if there is another language in use.
The Zepp app is a fitness app for android connected with a smart watch.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the Zepp app does not offer a way to get info from it then unfortunately you can't get any info

Comment: Which info are you after?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to know the heart rate for another project. I was asking if anyone had any experience or knowledge about where the values are stored.